# Django - ManytoOne relations and list of data entered by user

Tags: python, django, forms, foreign-keys, many-to-one

I am new to django but really want to learn how to use this framework.

*What  want to do :*

I have a form, that allows the user to create a new client for example.

**So in this form I have 3 fields :**

- Name
- Description
- Skills

The 'Skills' field is currently a text area, where the user would copy and paste a list already existing in another document(excel). Therefore, each element is separated by a splitline.

*What I would like to do is :*

- create in the database the client entered by the user
- In the database, link the description entered by the user to the client
- In the database, link each skill entered by the user to the name so that I can work on them independantly of each other in further functions/apps. I don't want all of the skills to be linked to the client as one big bloc.

So I read the documentation and thought about using a ForeignKey. The thing is I was unable to get an input text area when using a ForeignKey. Everytime I used it I got an empty 'select list' like this ...

[Empty list field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfgW8.png)

And even though I would be able to get that, I still don't know how to treat each element separatly of the others..

This is the code I have now :

model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    skills = models.TextField(null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'skills']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

post_form.html

```
{% extends "taskflow/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Client</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

As an example of what I tried to implement using a Foreign Key :

models.py

```
class Skills(models.Model):
    element = models.TextField(null=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    skills = models.ForeignKey(Skills, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'skills']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

If in views.py, instead of calling 'skills' I call 'element', I get an error saying 'element' is undefined.
I thought that using a ForeignKey would include the 'element' field contained in Skills in the 'skills' field contained in Post. So from what I understand it is not the case.

What am I doing wrong?

Any information and tips would be welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**Displaying foreign key field**

If you want to display `skills.element` in your view then you don't have to call `skills.element` in fields just define `__str__()` method in your Skills model.

```
class Skills(models.Model):
    element = models.TextField(null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.element
```

p.s. Regarding the relation between Post and Skill, I think it might be Many to Many because one `Post` can have **many** `Skills` and one `Skill` can belong **to** **many** `Posts` but your current model doesn't allow that (Any `Post` can have only **one** `Skill` while one `Skill` belong **to** **many** `Post`).

You can find out more about how to implement many to many relationship in Django at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: I tested what you advised and put def __str__ line. However, When calling the field 'skills' in view.py I still get this empty 'select field' instead of the textfield from 'element'. And if I directly call 'element' in views.py I get an error saying it is undefined.. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Try to create 1 skill in django admin page you'll see that the list is not empty. https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7o5f.png.

Comment: I think you should try this https://dev.to/zxenia/django-inline-formsets-with-class-based-views-and-crispy-forms-14o6. This post might be the solution of what you trying to achieve (Display inline form of Skill in the Post form)

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for since I dan't want the user to click on an 'add' button evry time he wants to add a data. I'd rather have a large TextField, where the user enter a list. And for each element of the list, create an instance in the database. I'll take a closer look to your link. And if I can't find a solution I'll probably use it.

Answer (score 0):

** I CHANGED SKILLS TO ADDRESS **

I thought about this :

- Get a TextField instead of ForeignKey
- the user enters his list like this for example :

[TextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrwtK.png)

- Then in Views.py I try to parse it, by creating a new field and use splitlines() like this:

  ```
    class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
        model = Post
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'address']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.address_list = self.object.address.splitlines()
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
  ```

Here I think i need to do something like

```
for element in self.object.address_list:
    #create object here
```

But I don't really know how to do it and most of the time I get

> Post object has no attribute object

And also, in my template if I use for example :

```
<p class="article-content">{{ post.address_list }}</p>
```

I get ['123456', '123457', '123458']

And if I use :

{{ post.address_list.1 }}

I'll get the first str character which is **'**

So the general idea would be to get from this form this output in the db :

[db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBoz9.png)

as I want to create an instance of each address in the db, linked to the client.

Thanks for your very appreciated help !